# Which symmetry is broken during an AdS black hole phase transition and does it lead to chaos?

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, phase-transition, symmetry-breaking, chaos-theory

I was going through [this paper](https://academic.oup.com/ptep/article/2021/7/073E01/6279754) in which the authors state that :

1. In Landau theory, a continuous phase transition is associated with a broken symmetry.
2. The phase transition in a black hole system can also be characterized by the symmetry and
   order degrees as in a conventional thermodynamic system.

The authors don't explicitly state which symmetry is broken for the black hole phase transition. Also, would such symmetry breaking lead to any chaotic effects? Any explanation in this regard would be truly beneficial.